# Plot a table of a scatterplot with 2 large arrays in python

Tags: python

I have two large arrays, one of actual measured values (actual) and one of computer model output values (model). The arrays are of different sizes (~11,000 for the model, ~700 for the actual). When using the code below on the two arrays, the column titles appear in the top row but all the values within the array are in the next row instead of separated. I have also tried saving the arrays into a CSV but the model values do not contain commas and thus cannot be read correctly. Also when viewing the arrays, they are not in the desired order such that the model array and the actual array are not correlated yet the scatter plot arranges the arrays accordingly.

Overall, I can plot the 2 datasets but the order is the issue. I need to find out how to include lat/lon into these masked arrays. A straight-up table of what is plotted in a scatterplot would be ideal. (scatterplot code followed by table code is below)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=72)
plt.scatter(model,actual, s=50, cmap=cmap)


plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'r') #1-1 fit line
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlim((0,10))
plt.ylim((0,10))
plt.xlabel('Modeled')
plt.ylabel('Actual')
plt.table(True) #gives error "table() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)"
```

The scatterplot image in this link. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNkxV.png)

Comment: You have about five questions bundled up in here. Could you clarify exactly what you're trying to ask?

Comment: Overall, I am trying to get the table of what is plotted in the scatterplot. I have tried using some examples of plotting a table with the plot but that tends to only work with a handful of datapoints listed in the code and not a large array. I have edited my code in the question to hopefully better convey what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand..so you want a table which lists all 700 of the actual values and all 11,000 of the model values? That would be a huge table so I assume I am misunderstanding. Maybe adding a sketch of what you're expecting to see would be helpful.

Comment: It will be a fairly large table but it will not include all of the model values. I added my scatter plot to the question to show that I only want a table of the scatterplot points (adcirc vs hwm in this case). a point is only plotted if there is a model value AND an actual value for that particular point. Therefore there are only 700 points as opposed to 11,000.  I am trying to plot the table of only the ordered pairs in this scatterplot and not the full datasets. I hope this clears things up